# Trying to solve 2D Summation Loop using MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science

So I'm trying to solve this problem in MIPS. [image: this is problem]

Here is my code in MIPS. On paper, the answer to this problem is 45. My program is outputting 27 and I'm not sure why.

```
  .text 
  .globl main
main:

  li $t1, 0 #sum
  li $t3, 1 #variable a

loop2:

  beq $t3, 4 done2 #loop until a = 3 only
  li $t0, 1 #variable b
  li $t2, 1 #stores constant 1

loop1:

  beq $t0, 4, done #loop until b = 3 only
  addi $t1, $t1, 1 #add +1 to sum
  add $t1, $t1, $t3 #add a to sum
  add $t0, $t0, 1 #increment b
  j loop1

done: 
  add $t3, $t3, 1 #increment a
  j loop2

done2:

  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $t1
  syscall
```

Comment: Why are you never adding `b` to the sum?

Comment: Where should it be added?

Comment: Same place where you do the other two adds.

Comment: So "add $t1, $t0, $t1? "

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. So if I was to have a 3D loop, I'd need to add a+b+c to the sum?

Comment: Only if the summation expression actually was a+b+c